# Unable to configure cancancan with active_admin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, cancancan

I am trying to make a blog website. I am using `active_admin` and `cancancan` gem. Two controllers I have made are `Post`, `Category`.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
    load_and_authorize_resource

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id, :published_at)
    end
end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < InheritedResources::Base
    load_and_authorize_resource
  private

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:category)
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  def admin?
    role == "admin"
  end
  def regular?
    role == "regular"
  end
  def guest?
    role == "guest"
  end
end
```

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    #user = User.new()
    if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
    else 
        can :read, :all 
    end
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_18_221247) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.date "published_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "category_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "role", default: "guest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

I am trying to define authorization based on `role`, role column is there in users table and by default new user is the guest user.

My goal is to allow a guest user to only read Posts.

**Problem**: I am getting access denied for both admin and guest user though I have clearly defined what different types of user can do in *ability.rb*.

If you need more info about the code you can check it on [**github**](https://github.com/Pushpamk/stackoverflow/tree/master/Test).

Comment: Do you have a separate AdminUser model?

Comment: no, only one users model with role attribute. You can see in schema.rb which I have attached in the question order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cancancan does not support InheritedResources anymore. see here: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Inherited-Resources

You need to use an adapter. CanCanCan supports only ActiveRecord and ActionController by default.

Comment: Since I am new to Rails , can you explain a little bit more How I can use an adapter with my current Rails Project?

Comment: why do you use InheritedResources in the first place?

Comment: actually when I executed `rails active_admin:resource Post`, it automatically changed to InheritedResources.